# How to navigate from one screen to another automatically in Xamarin cross platform app?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am not able to find out how to navigate from one screen to another automatically without having to click on any button or perform any action. I want to start another screen just after my splash screen shows up. As i am new on this tool or technology. Please help. Thank you in advance.

`My code is:`

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
     public MainPage()
     {
           InitializeComponent();
     }
     protected async override void OnAppearing()
     {
           base.OnAppearing();
           await Task.Delay(5000); // Simulate a bit of startup work.
           await this.Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working and tested code:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    GoToMaster();               
}

private async void GoToMaster()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    await this.Navigation.PushAsync(new SignUpPage());
}
```

Comment: That isn't working. I made my splash activity under xamarin.droid file and i want it to display the xaml file that i made in portable portion before launching the home page activity.

Comment: Add details like App.xaml and other code related to this. This is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

> I made my splash activity under xamarin.droid file and i want it to display the xaml file that i made in portable portion before launching the home page activity.

You can't skip the MainActivity as it is the container of your pages in Portable lib, So if you want to redirect to your xaml page after the splash screen, you can make SplashScreenActivity navigate to your MainActivity and make your xaml file the `MainPage` of `App.cs`:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new YourPage();
    }
    ....
}
```

And in your `SplashScreenActivity` you need to navigate to the `MainActivity`:

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(SplashActivity).Name;

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        Task startupWork = new Task(() => { SimulateStartup(); });
        startupWork.Start();
    }

    async void SimulateStartup()
    {
        await Task.Delay(8000);
        StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
    }
}
```

here is the complete demo:[SplashScreenDemo](https://github.com/elvisxia/SplashScreenDemo).

Comment: Thanks. If i want to display any image as my splash screen so do i need to make its axml page under Layouts portion of Xamarin.android ? Also navigation is now successful but i am not able to see the UI that i designed on my screen. It is showing a blank screen.

Comment: For Splash Screen, you can follow the [official doc](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/splash-screen/#drawable). For the blank screen issue, please create a new thread with detail for that.